# Django ModelForm Not Saving into Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have been struggling for the past couple of days trying to get my forms to save into my database. As of right now it is creating the object in the database but all of the fields inside the object are empty. I'm trying to save data from a ModelForm into the model.

Models.py

```
class ContactForm(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
Email = models.EmailField()
Phone = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
Message = models.CharField(max_length= 200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Name
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
message = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

class Meta:
    model = ContactForm
    fields = ['name','email','phone','message']
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

else:
    form = ContactForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'home/contact.html', args)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
url(r'^buy-now/$', views.buyNow, name='buy-now'),
url(r'^buy-form/$', views.buyForm, name='buy-form'),
url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'home/login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'home/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
url(r'^account/$', views.account, name='account'),
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
```

]

template contact.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
    <title>Aeviternus | Contact </title>
{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
{% block body %}
    <!-- Section: Contact -->
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card-panel teal white-text center">
              <i class="material-icons">email</i>
              <h5>Contact Us</h5>
              <p>If you have any comments or suggestions for any upcoming content or features you would like to see added, We want to hear about it.</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="collection with-header">
              <li class="collection-header">
                <h4>Location</h4>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">CSCI 152 Development Lab</li>
              <li class="collection-item">5241 N Maple Ave</li>
              <li class="collection-item">Fresno, CA 93740</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card-panel grey lighten-3">
              <h5>Please fill out this form</h5>
              <form method ="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form }}
              <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Submit</button>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
{% endblock %}
<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Sidenav
  const sideNav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
  M.Sidenav.init(sideNav, {});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your model name and form name are same. So, probably it's causing the problem.
change your form class name to `ContactModelForm`. Then your form class becomes

```
class ContactModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
  phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
  message = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

  class Meta:
    model = ContactForm
    fields = ['name','email','phone','message']
```

or

```
class ContactModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = ContactForm
    fields = ['Name','Email','Phone','Message']
```

and replace `ContactForm` with `ContactModelForm` in your views.

Comment: @TroySamra You have capitalized the fields in your model make it to lowercase letters like `Name` to `name` etc.

Comment: @TroySamra please accept the answer and give an upvote.

Comment: Was it wrong because in my class meta I had the fields listed in lowercase??

Comment: forgive me i am new to stack overflow how do i do this?

Comment: @TroySamra python is a case sensitive language it treats `Name` is different from `name`. So, the field names in the model must match in the forms